# density of dependent variable vs density of error term

Tags: regression, density-function, error

In a paper I found the following regression model:
  
  
$\ ln(V+a) = c+b*ln(X)+u$ 
  
where$\ u$ is normally distributed and $\ ln$ indicates the natural logarithm.
  
  
In order to find the density for$\ V $ they write:
  
$\ f(V) = f(u)*|du/dV| = 1/(V+a)*f(u)$
  
 where $\ f(.) $ are densities.
  
  
Why do they take the absolute value of derivative of the error term? How can we derive the distribution of a transformation of the dependent variable from the distribution of the error term?

Comment: Would it make any sense not to use the absolute value when the derivative is negative?

Comment: Ok, sure.. I meant why the whole solution for f(V) is that one..

Comment: The practical reason why you will see the absolute value show up when applying a monotone increasing transformation (where it is not *necessary*) is because the author is appealing to a general theorem that also covers the monotone decreasing case, where the absolute value is necessary. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables

Comment: Thank you Chris Haug! That was the formal explanation I was looking for! I had the feeling it must be a basic result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theoren used to recover the density of a transformation of a random variable is the following: $$f_{Y}(y)=f_{X}\left(g^{-1}(y)\right)\left|\frac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy}\right|$$
where $f_X$ is the density of the original variable and $f_Y$ is the density of the transformation $y=g(x)$.